# Show select div by button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help,
When I click the button to show the select div, the "id" generated by PHP, returns a `null` response in the console. I only need to show the div when I click on the "Cita rápida" button.

Here is the code:

```js
function muestraCita(id) {
  var ident = document.getElementById(id);
  ident.classList.add("showing");
};
```

```css
.showing {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 3%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cr-clase">
  <div class="cr-options">
    <img title="Proponer cita rápida" alt="Cita Rápida" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/cita-rapida-icon.gif">
  </div>
  <div class="button" onclick="muestraCita(cr21);">Cita Rápida</div>
  <div id="cr21" class="formdate">
    <form onsubmit="return validacionCita();target_popup()" action="/../../controladores/grabarglobal.php" target="done" method="post">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does cr21 start hidden? the argument to muestraCita should be in quotes if it's a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, cr21 starts display: none; yeah, muestracita is in quotes in onclick event

Comment: I meant like this muestraCita('cr21') -- otherwise cr21 is treated as a variable, which is undefined.

Comment: onclick="muestraCita(<?php echo "cr".ThemexUser::$data['active_user']['ID']; ?>);" this is the php code, i pasted a Firebug screen shot, the ID is between quotes i mean

Comment: It sould be `onclick="muestraCita('<?php echo "cr".ThemexUser::$data['active_user']['ID']; ?>');"` Notice the single quotes I added before `<?php` and after `?>`.

Comment: SOLVED!, you have reason, in the php code, i dont wrote the quotes.
Thanks Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
onclick="muestraCita(cr21);"
```

Written like that, the `cr21` is treated as a *variable* that has no value, but you need to pass a *string* to `muestraCita()`

You are missing the quotes. Try:

```
onclick="muestraCita('cr21');"
```